# CSS background image left half showing only on older IE

Tags: css

I have this CSS code:

```
body {
  background-image: url("url"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%; 
} on content {width: 80%;}
```

Works fine on Chrome and recent IE, but breaks older IE. In the error case, the image does not go the full width of browser and thus shows up only on the left while the right side becomes blank. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks. I actually wrote it like this:

body { 
background-image: url("url");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%; 
}

Comment: Can you reproduce this in http://jsfiddle.net? I'm curious as to why modern browsers are interpreting that 100% in your shorthand as a `background-size` value when they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's time to break out the conditional tags for shotty IE browsers.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

My favorite is adding a unique style sheet for legacy browsers this chap covers it well.

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Good luck. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: This answers how to make something IE specific, but it doesn't answer why the image is getting cut off or how to fix it.